# Bound on $ab+ac+bc$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

It is obvious that for real positive numbers we have $ab+ac+cb \le a^2+b^2+c^2,$ but I would like to know if there is a better bound on the expression  $ab+ac+cb $ than that.

Comment: "Better" in which sense? Obviously you cannot achieve $$ ab+ac+bc \leq K(a^2+b^2+c^2) $$ for a constant $K<1$, since the inequality has to hold in the case $a=b=c$, too.

Comment: Define better.  GM-HM gets us $ab+ac+bc \leq 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$.

Comment: well in the sense that $ab+ac+cb \le f(a,b,c) \le a^2+b^2+c^2$

Comment: How about $ab+ac+bc+.001$, that's a good bound.

Comment: @XinWang: well, $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(ab+ac+bc) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\right].$$ Draw your conclusions.

Comment: @LeeMosher and failed my previous requirement...also taking the left or right hand side is also not permitted

Comment: I think the problem is that your requirements are not entirely clear.  You want something that's homogeneous in $a, b, c$ and is a bound that dominates $a^2+b^2+c^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better bound would be $0.9(ab+bc+ca) + 0.1(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

Comment: wow, this bound works amazing, exactly what i was looking for